# Member pointer being overwritten on function return?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, binary-search-tree, memory-corruption

I've been practicing my C++, as it's gotten a little rusty since college, and I'm having a bizarre problem where a member value is being overwritten as soon as my function returns.

```
template <class T>
class BstNode
{
    public:
        T value;
        BstNode<T>* left;
        BstNode<T>* right;
        BstNode<T>* parent;

        BstNode()
        { left = right = parent = NULL; }
        BstNode(T value)
        { this->value=value; left=right=parent=NULL;}
        BstNode(T value, BstNode<T>* parent)
        { this->value=value; this->parent=parent; left=right=NULL;}
};

template <class T>
class BinarySearchTree 
{
    protected:
        BstNode<T>* root;

        void removeNode(BstNode<T>* node);
        void addChild(T value, BstNode<T>* node);
        BstNode<T>* find(T value, BstNode<T>* node);
    public:
        BinarySearchTree()
        { root = NULL; }
        ~BinarySearchTree()
        { removeNode(root); }

        BinarySearchTree<T> insert(T value);
        bool contains(T value);
        BinarySearchTree<T> remove(T value);

        void print();

        BstNode<T>* getRoot() {return root;}

};

template <class T>
BinarySearchTree<T> BinarySearchTree<T>::insert(T value)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new BstNode<T>(value);       
    }
    else
    {
        addChild(value, root);
    }
    cout << "VAL: " << root->value << endl << "LEFT: " << root->left << endl << "RIGHT: "<< root->right << endl << "ADDR: " << root <<endl;
    return *this;
}
template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::addChild(T value, BstNode<T>* node)
{

    if (value > node->value)
    {
        cout <<"\tgt"<<endl;
        if (node->right == NULL)
        {
            node->right = new BstNode<T>(value, node);
        }
        else
        {
            addChild(value, node->right);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\tlte"<<endl;
        if (node->left == NULL)
        {
            node->left = new BstNode<T>(value, node);
        }
        else
        {
            addChild(value, node->left);
        }
    }
}

// [other member functions]


int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree<int> tree;
    BstNode<int> *n;
    n = tree.getRoot();
    cout << "ADDR: " << n <<endl<<endl;
    tree.insert(5);
    n = tree.getRoot();

    cout << "VAL: " << n->value << endl << "LEFT: " << n->left << endl << "RIGHT: "<< n->right << endl << "ADDR: " << n << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

The output of my function is:

```
$ ./bst
ADDR: 0

VAL: 5
LEFT: 0
RIGHT: 0
ADDR: 0xa917c8

VAL: 11085080
LEFT: 0xa917a8
RIGHT: 0
ADDR: 0xa917c8
```

I don't understand why the values in the root node changed, but the pointer is still pointing at the same location. The only thing I could think of is that the root node is being created on the stack instead being allocated in the heap, but doesn't `new` make sure that memory is allocated correctly in C++?

Comment: Can you post the code fore `addChild`?  The problem appears to be there

Comment: Your example code only outputs VAL once. Where are you getting the second VAL output from?

Comment: One comes from main, and one from insert

Comment: There is a val output in main() and in BinarySearchTree::insert(). The one inside insert is printing the correct/intended values, and the one in main is printing random/garbage values.

Comment: Where is the code for `addChild` ?

Comment: I tested this code and got correct output.  addChild never gets called - are you sure your code that you used to print the output doesn't have addChild in main() and is different from the code you posted?  Asking because your 2nd LEFT variable appears to have a child at a valid pointer location.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `addChild` isn't being executed. root is (demonstrated) NULL for the first insert, so the `else` block isn't being hit. (Plus the lt/gt isn't being printed to terminal.) It isn't being run from main(), it's protected. Although that **does** look like a valid memory location...

Comment: Trying to reproduce your problem, my system prints out the correct output.

Comment: templatetypedef has a good answer. As to why it works for us, we don't have an implementation of `removeNode` so the tree destructor is doing nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that your insert method returns the BinarySearchTree by value, but you don't have a copy constructor defined.  As a result, this makes a shallow copy of the BinarySearchTree, returns it, and causes the copy's destructor to fire.  This then deletes the BstNode stored as the root, but since the copied BinarySearchTree shares BstNodes with the original tree, you're trashing memory in the original tree.  The error you're getting is from accessing deallocated memory when you try to access the node again.

To fix this, either have the insert function return a reference to the tree (so no copy is made) or define a copy constructor or assignment operator.  Ideally, do both. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, didn't see that, but yes adding a `He dead Jim` cout to the destructor show that it is run, we don't get the error because we are lacking the implementation of `removeNode` and thus don't deallocate any memory.

Comment: This was it, thanks! I was returning `*this` so I could chain together insert calls - tree.insert(5).insert(10).insert(-3), etc - like I was trained to do in Java and C#. I guess in C++, I should be using the dereferencing `->` instead of the dot to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @AndrewRueckert- In C++, you would have the function return a BinarySearchTree& (a reference to the object) instead of a BinarySearchTree (a copy of the object).  The Java and C# trick still works here, but you have to explicitly state that you will return the reference.  In Java and C#, all objects are passed around by reference, but in C++ pass-by-value is the default.